# How to get velocity from PSD graph

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, power-spectral-density, autoregressive-model

[image: Spectra inside cavity. PSD vs. frequency]

Hello everyone!
I have a graph, which is Spectra inside cavity. PSD vs. frequency.
I need to get velocity [m/s] from PSD [dB/Hz].
Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the sound pressure level from PSD, and the velocity is related to the sound pressure. According to the equation of motion,

$$
\rho \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{v}}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\nabla p \tag{1}
$$

where $\rho$ is the density of the medium, $\vec{v}$ is the particle velocity, $\nabla=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\vec{i}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\vec{j}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\vec{k}$ is the gradient operator, and $p$ is the sound pressure. When the sound is not so loud, the equation of motion can be linearized and the total derivative $\mathrm{d}\vec{v}/\mathrm{d}t$ becomes partial derivative $\partial{\vec{v}}/\partial{t}$.

Furthermore, if you make a plane wave assumption, then the particle velocity amplitude is

$$
v = \pm \frac{p}{\rho_0 c_0} \tag{2}
$$

for plane waves of forward and backward propagation, respectively. $\rho_0$ and $c_0$ are respective the medium density and sound speed without acoustic disturbance. Their product $\rho_0 c_0$ is the characteristic specific acoustic impedance of the medium.

However, your data is acquired in a cavity with an extremely high level of PSD, thus the linearization is obviously inappropriate. The total derivative in Eq. (1) should be

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{v}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} \\
= \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} + v_x\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial x}+ v_y\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial y}+ v_z\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial z} 
\tag{3}
$$

In addition, velocity is also related to frequency, but it seems that you want an overall velocity. You can obtain the time-domain sound pressure according to the Parseval's theorem, and then calculate the particle velocity.

Comment: Thank you so much!